# Paypal .net MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, paypal, methodaccessexception

I want to implement Paypal into my **WPF-Application** and created a TestProject. Everything works fine but when I transfer the written code into my existing project, I get a **MethodAccessException** at line

```
var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret, sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();
```

> Fehler beim Versuch der SecurityTransparent-Methode "PayPal.Api.OAuthTokenCredential.GenerateOAuthToken()", auf die sicherheitskritische Methode "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(System.String)" zuzugreifen.
>   Die Assembly "PayPal, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b4afc1ccaef40fb" ist mit "AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute" markiert und verwendet das Sicherheitstransparenzmodell der Stufe 2. Bei Festlegung der Transparenz auf Stufe 2 werden alle Methoden in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers-Assemblys standardmäßig sicherheitstransparent, was die Ursache der Ausnahme sein kann.

I don't know what this message would look like in english, so sorry for writing it in german.

Hopefully someone could tell me what is happening here

Thanks!

Comment: Do you run your existing project in a hosted environment?

Comment: What do you mean with hosted environment? Both the testcode and realcode are running inside a virtual machine on my server

Comment: I meant if you run it on Azure or Amazon for example. Could you try updating your config file inside the `<system.web>` block with the following line and see if it makes a difference: `<trust level="Full" />`?

Comment: I see, well no I don't, like I said, it is running on my own server. And I forgot to mention that it is a WPF-Application

Comment: Try changing the trust level as per my comment

Comment: cannot find where to put this line in, because I am using WPF there is no web.config file and adding it into App.config with creating **<system.web>** still throws the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130218/discussion-between-silkfire-and-daniel-dirtynative-martin).